# How to get sum at each column in multi column groups for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Below is a dataframe.

```
  team task day  in  out
0    A    X   M  60   11
1    A    X   T  80   12
2    A    Y   M  91   31
3    A    Y   T  11   21
4    B    X   M  32   13
5    B    X   T  18   33
6    B    Z   M  28   42
7    B    Z   T  15   15
```

When groupby is performed with multiple columns, the output is as below.

`df.groupby(['team', 'task','day']).sum()`

```
               in  out
team task day         
A    X    M    60   11
          T    80   12
     Y    M    91   31
          T    11   21
B    X    M    32   13
          T    18   33
     Z    M    28   42
          T    15   15
```

In the same output, I am looking to get the sum for each column level i.e. at team, task level as well.
As shown below.

```
               in  out
team task day         
A              242   75   <<<<<
A    X         140   23   <<<<<  
A    X    M    60   11
          T    80   12
A    Y         102   52   <<<<<
     Y    M    91   31
          T    11   21
B              93   103   <<<<<
B    X         50   46    <<<<<
B    X    M    32   13
          T    18   33
B    Z         43   57    <<<<
     Z    M    28   42
          T    15   15
```

I get the sum for these columns when performed the grouping separately.

`df.groupby(['team', 'task','day']).sum()`
`df.groupby(['team', 'task']).sum()`
`df.groupby(['team']).sum()`

```
team task day         
A    X    M    60   11
          T    80   12
     Y    M    91   31
          T    11   21
B    X    M    32   13
          T    18   33
     Z    M    28   42
          T    15   15
            in  out
team task          
A    X     140   23
     Y     102   52
B    X      50   46
     Z      43   57
       in  out
team          
A     242   75
B      93  103
```

I am looking for the combined output of sum done at each level as explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
a = df.groupby(['team', 'task','day']).sum()
b = df.groupby(['team', 'task']).sum()
c = df.groupby(['team']).sum()

b['day'] = None
c[['task', 'day']] = None

a = a.reset_index()
b = b.reset_index()
c = c.reset_index()

result = pd.concat(
    [a, b, c],
).set_index(
    ['team', 'task', 'day'],
).sort_index(
    na_position="first",
)
```

This is the output:

```
>>> result
                in  out
team task day          
A    NaN  NaN  242   75
     X    NaN  140   23
          M     60   11
          T     80   12
     Y    NaN  102   52
          M     91   31
          T     11   21
B    NaN  NaN   93  103
     X    NaN   50   46
          M     32   13
          T     18   33
     Z    NaN   43   57
          M     28   42
          T     15   15
```

Comment: This works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and reworking the `MultiIndex`:

```
cols = ['in', 'out']

out = pd.concat([df.groupby(['team'])[cols].sum(),
                 df.groupby(['team', 'task'])[cols].sum(),
                 df.groupby(['team', 'task','day'])[cols].sum(), 
                ])

out.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(pd.DataFrame.from_records(out.index),
                                     names=['team', 'task', 'day'])

out = out.sort_index(na_position='first')
```

Output:

```
                in  out
team task day          
A    NaN  NaN  242   75
     X    NaN  140   23
          M     60   11
          T     80   12
     Y    NaN  102   52
          M     91   31
          T     11   21
B    NaN  NaN   93  103
     X    NaN   50   46
          M     32   13
          T     18   33
     Z    NaN   43   57
          M     28   42
          T     15   15
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but when the team has more than 1 character its getting split.